# Manually closing subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, kill

I am using

```
std = subprocess.PIPE
```

and checking a particular term in every line of the output.If I get 'done', I manually kill the subprocess by os.kill :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['vprobe' ,'/vprobe/myhello.emt'], shell = False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
while True:
   line = p.stdout.readline()
   logfile.write(line)
   if re.search("done", line):
      break
   print "waiting"
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

The process does get killed (i checked using the 'ps' command in unix) but at the end I get an error that:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook:
Original exception was:
```

which I think is most probably because I have killed the process without actually closing the PIPE. Any suggestions how I can manually do it?

Comment: @cdarke `std` is `subprocess.PIPE`, which is just `-1` (or was it `-2`?) and which has no `.close()`...

Answer (score 1):

The `Popen` object has a [`terminate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) method meant to do this. Could you not use this method instead?

If you really want to kill with `SIGINT` there is also a `send_signal` method.

Comment: ,Weirdly none of the following commands seems to work: p.kill(), p.terminate(). it says there is no object named 'kill'. But however, I got the solution. I used SIGTERM instead of SIGINT. That closed the PIPE too.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: The methods `kill` and `terminate` were introduced in Python 2.6. It seems you are using an older version.

Comment: @RolandSmith ya, that's the point. I am using python 2.6.7, still 
gives the error: AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'kill'

Comment: @Core_Dumped: Could it be that you have different versions of python installed?

Comment: @Core_Dumped are you on Windows?

Comment: @Krumelur No sir, I am working on CentOS
RolandSmith versions? I guess I only have python 2.6.7 installed

Comment: Both `terminate` and `kill` should be available on Python 2.6.7.