# terminate a linux command line utility from python

Tags: python, linux, angstrom-linux

I've got a command line utility from `canutils` called `candump`. It works like this:

I run candump (specifying the bus from which I want to dump)

```
root@beaglebone: candump can0
```

It then runs until I end it using `CTRL+C`

However, when I run it in a python script like so.

```
Popen(["candump","can0"],stdout=PIPE)
```

or

```
call(["candump","can0"])
```

I'm not sure how to end it. Any ideas?

Comment: [Relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030162/manually-closing-subprocess-pipe)

Comment: `Popen.terminate()` and `Popen.kill()` should work if you don't want to use `send_signal`. [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use use the call command if you want control over the subprocess

If you use Popen like you did above you should assign it to a variable like this:

```
p = Popen(["candump","can0"],stdout=PIPE)
```

Once you have p then you can use one of the following SIGNAL commands on it
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal

Answer (score 2):

Use `Popen()`, and call `send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` on the returned `Popen` object.